# Template Constructor for Primitives, avoiding Ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a constructor for a class that needs a value, signedness, and width.  Here is an example constructor for it:

```
Foo::Foo(char c) //let's just assume sizeof(char)=1
  : init(c, true, 8)
{}
```

However I want to do this for ALL `std::is_integral` types so that the compiler will implicitly convert when I overload functions like `operator*()`.  For instance, the following should compile just fine:

```
Foo a = 1; //same as Foo a(1);
Foo b = a * 2;
```

I could make the constructor a template like this:

```
struct Foo{
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T t)
      : init(t, std::is_signed<T>::value, sizeof(T)*8)
    {}
};
```

However I also want to include some additional constructors for `std::string` and other things.  Is there a way I could use the template for primitive types, and then my other constructors for non primitives (right now I get ambiguity errors)? I have a feeling that I need to manually make constructors for all of the primitives and the `<stdint>` typedefs...

My first attempt is the following, but this doesn't seem to be working

```
struct Foo{ 
  template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,int>::type>
  Foo(const T& t)
    : init(t, std::is_signed<T>::value, sizeof(T)*8)
  {}
};
```

My following test fails:

```
unsigned int uint;
Foo uintFoo(uint);
//undefined reference to 'Foo::Foo(unsigned int const&)'
```

Comment: Just a little question: what is `init`?

Comment: I think for the purposes of this question, let's say it's `void init(long long, bool, int);`.  That way all inputs to the first value will be cast up while the remaining inputs retain the signedness and width characteristics.